# Creating custom touch gestures using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, gesture-recognition, hammer.js

I need to create custom gestures for different shapes like square, circle etc. In other words i need to detect when user draws a square or circle on their touch device using javascript.

currently i'm trying to achieve this by using [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) [custom gestures](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Custom-Gestures)
so far i can detect whenever user draws something and the code looks like

```
  var obj= { 
name: 'draw',
index: 7,
defaults: {
  max_draw_dur:200,
  min_delta_x:100,
  min_delta_y:200
},
centerX:undefined,
centerY:undefined,
changingDir:false,
changeInDir:0,
startangle:0,
currDir:undefined,
currDX:0,
currDY:0,
handler: function(ev, inst) {
if(Hammer.detection.previous!=undefined) {
     var prev = Hammer.detection.previous;
     var curr = Hammer.detection.current;
     switch (ev.eventType) {
        case Hammer.EVENT_START:
           this.changeInDir=0;
           this.startangle=0;
           this.centerX=curr.startEvent.center.pageX;
           this.centerY=curr.startEvent.center.pageY;
           Hammer.detection.current.name = 'draw'
           inst.trigger(this.name, ev);
           break;
        case Hammer.EVENT_MOVE:

              if (Math.abs(ev.angle-this.startangle)>=45&&Math.abs(ev.angle-this.startangle)<=180) {

                 Hammer.detection.current.name = 'draw'
                 this.startangle=ev.angle;
                 this.changeInDir++;
              }
           break;
        case Hammer.EVENT_END:
        if (curr.name==this.name && this.changeInDir>=2 && this.changeInDir<=7) {
           this.changeInDir=0;
           this.startangle=0;
           inst.trigger(this.name+'Circle', ev);
           // trigger gesture event
        }
        else if (this.changeInDir>=2 && this.changeInDir<=4) {
           this.changeInDir=0;
           this.startangle=0;
           inst.trigger(this.name+'Square', ev);
           // trigger gesture event
        }
        break;
     }      
    } 
  }
}
Hammer.detection.register(obj);
```

however i am not  able to make accurate gestures like a square using this. (major problem being even a slight change in any axis will trigger an event in that direction)

is there any other plugins that'll be helpful for achieving this? would be great if someone can point me in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure javascript version of the one-dollar single-stroke recognizer. Its open to expansion - u can add your own gestures on their website - and the JS is pretty easy to understand. https://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/

Another option is the jquery-based fancy gestures recognizer: http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/21/jquery-fancy-gestures/